# How to use laravel as backend on Intel xdk?

Tags: laravel, intel-xdk

I'm very noob on programming and using xdk. Do you how to use it?. I know you need to create rest web service for your laravel and then you call it using xdk, but how? do I need to have a web hosting service for this? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Intel XDK was the technology, similar to Cordova, used to develop cross platform applications. To develop native mobile apps you should look at Cordova or  nativescript
To host any kind of application which is based on php backend, needs a web server like nginx, apache etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a web hosting service.Put all your laravel code on server and interact with app using rest web service via XHR or Ajax Requests.